Windows 11: Unbind Win+Alt+Arrows
How can I unbind WIN+ALT in Windows 11?
I use WinDivvy, a window snapping tool (https://mizage.com/windivvy/) that has a very useful feature for me- I can define overlapping snap targets, so it's better for me than Windows 11's snap feature.
In Windows 10, I have hotkeys defined as WIN+ALT+Arrows.
In Windows 11, windows is eating WIN+ALT with "Snap windows" turned off in settings.

There are add-ons (e.g., Microssoft's own PowerToys) that can edit keyboard shortcuts: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/customize-windows-11-keyboard-shortcuts/ . Some may not be editable, such as Ctrl+Shift+Win+Alt, which opens https://www.microsoft365.com/?from=OfficeKey.
